# RtlWerpReportException, application crashed

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have this Message on QT: **Error - 
RtlWerpReportException failed with status code :-1073741823. Will try to launch the process directly.**
I use OpenTwebst, this my code:

ICore ptr;

```
IBrowser *pBrowser = new IBrowser;

ptr.setControl("{7C3D11C2-14A2-45cb-A40F-6696D6685021}");

pBrowser = ptr.StartBrowser("http://sesam.sso.infra.ftgroup/LoginDispatch");

if(!pBrowser)
{
    pBrowser = new IBrowser;
    pBrowser = ptr.FindBrowser("URL=http://sesam.sso.infra.ftgroup/LoginDispatch");
}

ptr.setSearchTimeout(30000);
ptr.setLoadTimeout(60000);

while(pBrowser->isLoading())
    continue;

if(pBrowser->FindElement("a","uiname=SIO"))
    pBrowser->FindElement("a","uiname=SIO")->Click();
```

Can we catch this exception on QT?
Thank you.

Comment: In order to answer this kind of question we need a [mcve].

Comment: sorry,now i just added the code

Comment: FWIW, the error code is actually 0xC0000001 (ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION). Try googling "RtlWerpReportException failed with status code qt" and you'll quite some related hits. Otherwise please provide a truly "minimal, _complete_ and _verifiable_" example like @Johan said. A code snippet won't likely help.

Comment: I 'm using namespace OpenTwebstLib from https://github.com/codecentrix/open-twebst, that can answer your question?thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in my headers :

```
#include "OPENTWEBSTQT.h"

using namespace OpenTwebstLib;
```

OPENTWEBSTQT.h is a file that I built from https://github.com/codecentrix/open-twebst